# How to access a user's stream?

Tags: soundcloud

new to the SoundCloud API.

Say I am a registered user.  I upload a couple of tracks and they appear on my page when I log into soundcloud at: https://soundcloud.com/stream

Using the API, I can now access data re my uploaded tracks.

If I then follow other users, these users' tracks will also appear at https://soundcloud.com/stream.  However, I could not find in the API Docs any way to access data for my tracks + tracks of users I follow.  Any way to do this ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the SoundCloud documentation got updated: the user's activities, quoted as being "the items on the logged in user's dashboard" *can* be fetched. You can even get specific types of items on this Dashboard.

When you process a `GET` request with this URL
 `$ curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?limit=1&oauth_token=A_VALID_TOKEN'`, you have a JSON or XML file (see at the bottom of the answer) that contains the informations you requested. In this URL, you can replace `/me/activities` by these expressions:

`/me/activities` gives you user's recent activities
`/me/activities/all` is the same as the one above (Recent activities)
`/me/activities/tracks/affiliated` is the recent tracks from users the logged-in user follows (the *stream*)
`/me/activities/tracks/exclusive` is recent exclusively shared tracks
`/me/activities/all/own` is recent activities on the logged-in users tracks

JSON responses follow this scheme:

```
{
  "next_href": "https://api.soundcloud.com/...?cursor=81923e19...",
  "collection": [
    {
      "type":       "comment",
      "created_at": "2011/07/21 09:55:19 +0000",
      "tags":       "own, affiliated",
      "origin": {
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
   ]
}
```

XML responses follow this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<activities next-href="https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities?cursor=0fc02662-1d76-11e0-8c9a-48ea6afb1384" type="array">
  <activity>
    ...
  </activity>
  ...
</activities>
```

For deeper and more precise informations about this functionnality, check [SoundCloud's API Reference documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. We do not currently offer a public API for this type of mixed data.

Comment: That's too bad.  Would you know what would be the appropriate channel through which to ask SoundCloud to possibly implement this ?

Comment: Could you describe your use case for this?

Comment: I'm working on integrating Soundcloud to a web app and would simply like to allow users to access these tracks.